# Java Replacing a Field (String/Int) with delimiter from file

Tags: java, replace

i got this code below to do replacing of a field that can be either String or Int but it is not working as expected. What i would like to do is inside the file player.dat the fields are "Username|Password|No. of Chips" i would like to replace the 3rd field based on username and i used string replace to change the old string to the new string but it is not working it is just adding the number next to the old value and all my data in file is messed up from the original line by line. Need some help on this

Current Output:

```
Username1|HashedPassword|200200Username2|HashedPassword2|300200Username3|HashedPassword3|300200
```

Expected Output

```
Username1|HashedPassword|200
Username2|HashedPassword|300
Username3|HashedPassword|200
```

Codes Shown Below.

```
 public class testcode {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new testcode().replace();
   }

   public void replace() {
      String oldFileName = "players.dat";
      String tmpFileName = "tempmod.dat";

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      ArrayList<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
         String line;
         Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Username");
         String UserN = read.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please Enter Chips to Add");
         String UserCadd = read.nextLine();

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] details = line.split("\\|");
                String Username = details[0];
                String Password = details[1];
                String Chips = details[2];
                int totalChips = Integer.parseInt(UserCadd) + Integer.parseInt(Chips);
            if (Username.equals(UserN))
               line = Username + "|" + Password + "|" +totalChips;
            bw.write("\r\n"+line);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         return;
      } finally {
         try {
            if(br != null)
               br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
         try {
            if(bw != null)
               bw.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            //
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: So your actual problem is that the adding of the integer value is not working? Have a look at this answer to learn how to convert a string to a integer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java You need to do that before the add operation.

Comment: Open the .dat file in other software like `notepad++`.. in some editors `\n` does not work for .dat file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148004/ignoring-end-of-line-character-in-a-dat-file-in-db2-import-command-while-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it manually:

```
Integer totalChips = (Integer.parseInt(UserCadd) + Integer.parseInt(Chips));
line = Username+"|"+Password+"|"+totalChips;
```

Comment: Does not work... the old String still remain or should i delete the old line first

Comment: The error as user1717259 said is that you are concatenating the Integers, you should add them before.

Comment: Thx but what the arrangement of the data because the line gets messed up into 1 long line instead of 3 separate lines

Comment: Concatenate a "\n" after then.

Answer (score 0):

`String totalChips = UserCadd + Chips;`

This is a String concatenation, rather than a numerical addition, so you end up with `200200`.

I think you want to add the actual numbers instead before your replace the old value. Have a look at `Integer.parseInt()`